# Index on array element attribute extremely slow

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongodb but not new to databases.  I created a collection of documents that look like this:

{_id: ObjectId('5e0d86e06a24490c4041bd7e')
,
,
match[{
_id: ObjectId(5e0c35606a24490c4041bd71),
ts: 1234456,
,
,}]
}

So there is a list of objects on the documents and within the list there might be many objects with the same _id field.  I have a handful of documents in this collection and my query that selects on selected match._id's is horribly slow.  I mean unnaturally slow.

Query is simply this: {match: {$elemMatch: {_id:match._id }}} and literally hangs the system for like 15 seconds returning 15 matching documents out of 25 total!

I put an index on the collection like this:
collection.createIndex({"match._id" : 1}) but that didn't help.

Explain says execution time is 0 and says it's using the index but it still takes 15 seconds or longer to complete.

I'm getting the same slowness in nodejs and in compass.

Explain Output:
{"explainVersion":"1","queryPlanner":{"namespace":"hp-test-39282b3a-9c0f-4e1f-b953-0a14e00ec2ef.lead","indexFilterSet":false,"parsedQuery":{"match":{"$elemMatch":{"_id":{"$eq":"5e0c3560e5a9e0cbd994fa52"}}}},"maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached":false,"maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached":false,"maxScansToExplodeReached":false,"winningPlan":{"stage":"FETCH","filter":{"match":{"$elemMatch":{"_id":{"$eq":"5e0c3560e5a9e0cbd994fa52"}}}},"inputStage":{"stage":"IXSCAN","keyPattern":{"match._id":1},"indexName":"match._id_1","isMultiKey":true,"multiKeyPaths":{"match._id":["match"]},"isUnique":false,"isSparse":false,"isPartial":false,"indexVersion":2,"direction":"forward","indexBounds":{"match._id":["[ObjectId('5e0c3560e5a9e0cbd994fa52'), ObjectId('5e0c3560e5a9e0cbd994fa52')]"]}}},"rejectedPlans":[]},"executionStats":{"executionSuccess":true,"nReturned":15,"executionTimeMillis":0,"totalKeysExamined":15,"totalDocsExamined":15,"executionStages":{"stage":"FETCH","filter":{"match":{"$elemMatch":{"_id":{"$eq":"5e0c3560e5a9e0cbd994fa52"}}}},"nReturned":15,"executionTimeMillisEstimate":0,"works":16,"advanced":15,"needTime":0,"needYield":0,"saveState":0,"restoreState":0,"isEOF":1,"docsExamined":15,"alreadyHasObj":0,"inputStage":{"stage":"IXSCAN","nReturned":15,"executionTimeMillisEstimate":0,"works":16,"advanced":15,"needTime":0,"needYield":0,"saveState":0,"restoreState":0,"isEOF":1,"keyPattern":{"match._id":1},"indexName":"match._id_1","isMultiKey":true,"multiKeyPaths":{"match._id":["match"]},"isUnique":false,"isSparse":false,"isPartial":false,"indexVersion":2,"direction":"forward","indexBounds":{"match._id":["[ObjectId('5e0c3560e5a9e0cbd994fa52'), ObjectId('5e0c3560e5a9e0cbd994fa52')]"]},"keysExamined":15,"seeks":1,"dupsTested":15,"dupsDropped":0}},"allPlansExecution":[]},"command":{"find":"lead","filter":{"match":{"$elemMatch":{"_id":"5e0c3560e5a9e0cbd994fa52"}}},"skip":0,"limit":0,"maxTimeMS":60000,"$db":"hp-test-39282b3a-9c0f-4e1f-b953-0a14e00ec2ef"},"serverInfo":{"host":"Dans-MacBook-Pro.local","port":27017,"version":"5.0.9","gitVersion":"6f7dae919422dcd7f4892c10ff20cdc721ad00e6"},"serverParameters":{"internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes":104857600,"internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes":104857600,"internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes":104857600,"internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes":104857600,"internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes":104857600,"internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS":0,"internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes":104857600,"internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes":104857600},"ok":1}

Comment: Please share the explain output

Comment: added above.  sorry I don't know how to format that better

Answer (score 0):

The `explain` output confirms that the operation that was explained is perfectly efficient. In particular we see:

- The expected index being used with tight `indexBounds`
- Efficient access of the data (`totalKeysExamined == totalDocsExamined == nReturned`)
- No meaningful duration (`"executionTimeMillis":0` which implies that the operation took less than `0.5ms` for the database to execute)

Therefore the slowness that you're experiencing for that particular operation is not related to the efficiency of the plan itself. This doesn't always rule out the database (or its underlying server) as the source of the slowness completely, but it is usually a pretty strong indicator that either the problem is elsewhere or that there are multiple factors at play.

I would suggest the following as potential next steps:

- Check the `mongod` log file (you can confirm its location by running `db.adminCmd("getCmdLineOpts")` via the shell connected to the instance). By default any operation slower than `100ms` is captured. This will help in a variety of ways:

  - If there is a log entry (with a meaningful duration) then it confirms that the slowness is being introduced while the database is processing the operation. It could also give some helpful hints as to why that might be the case (waiting for locks or server resources such as storage for example).
  - If an associated entry *cannot* be found, then that would be significantly stronger evidence that we are looking in the wrong place for the source of the slowness.
- Is the operation that you gathered `explain` for the *exact* one that the application and Compass are observing as being slow? Were you connected to the same server and namespace? Is the explained operation simplified in some way, such as the original operation containing sort, projection, collation, etc?

  - As a relevant example that combines these two, I notice that there are `skip` and `limit` parameters applied to the command explained on a `mongod` seemingly running on a laptop. Are those parameters non-zero when running the application and does the application run against a different database with a larger data set?
- The `explain` command doesn't include *everything* that an application would. Notably absent is the actual time it takes to send the results across the network. If you had particularly large documents that could be a factor, though  it seems unlikely to be the culprit in this particular situation.
- How exactly are you measuring the full execution time? Does it potentially include the time to connect to the database? In this case you mentioned that Compass itself also demonstrates the slowness, so that may rule out most of this.
- What else is running on the server hosting the database? Is there a container or VM involved? Would the database or the underlying server be experiencing resource contention due to concurrency?

Two additional minor asides:

- 25 total documents in a collection is extremely small. I would expect even the smallest hardware to be able to process such a request without an index unless there was some complicating factor.
- Assuming that `match` is always an array then the `$elemMatch` operator is not strictly necessary for this particular query. You can read more about that [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition). I would not expect this to have a performance impact for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly detailed response!  I will look into each bullet.  I thought this wouldn't need an index either at this stage.  I mean there are only 25 docs.  Just getting started on this.  The response is slow for both compass and my node app so perhaps there is something at the driver level I don't yet understand.  And I am just running on a localhost Mac, so maybe something there as well.

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped. 25 documents is really "nothing" at all, so I strongly suspect something else is going on here. Finding, or failing to find, an entry in the log file is going to be really informative about where to look next. Certainly feels like some sort of initiation or stall type of issue